# Sprite won't change with direction

Tags: unity, c#, sprites

I am making a top down Pacman game. I have two sprites: one for facing up and one for facing left.

When I press W, the sprite showing is still the one for when Pacman is moving left, but I want to see the up sprite instead.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pacman : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed;
    Vector2 dest;
    public Transform[] points;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        dest = transform.position;
        speed = 25;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
       // GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);

        // Check for Input if not moving
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, points[0].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GameObject.Find("up").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, points[2].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, points[1].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, points[3].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GameObject.Find("left").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;                
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a pure syntax problem that has nothing to do with game-development specific concepts. I'd recommend working though some more basic C# tutorials until you have a solid grasp of the fundamentals like how control flow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use curly braces { } to group together statements that you want to execute only when the condition of the `if` statement is met.

```
if (condition)
   DoActionA();

DoActionB();
```

This says "Do action A only if `condition` is `true`, but always do action B no matter what"

```
if (condition)
{
    DoActionA();
    DoActionB();
}
```

This instead says "Do action A then action B only if `condition` is `true`, otherwise skip them both"

So, specific fixes:

1. Don't call GetComponent every frame. That's just wasteful. Instead, call it during start-up and cache the result.
2. Put the sprite assignments inside braces to bundle them with the `if` statements that should control them.

Like so:

```
// You could just make these public variables and assign the sprite in the inspector.
Sprite upSprite;
Sprite leftSprite;

SpriteRenderer myRenderer;

void Start()
{
    dest = transform.position;
    speed = 25;

    // Cache our sprites & renderer.
    myRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    upSprite = GameObject.Find("up").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
    leftSprite = GameObject.Find("left").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;  
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("w")) {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, points[0].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        myRenderer.sprite = upSprite;
    }
    if...
```